# After render the changes in value show the changed one in the top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had some issue here to figure it out:
1 - I have a table of a lot of items
2 - each item have a button to change the status to finished
3 - when I press the button of status change appears a modal to finish the status
4 - so when I press my rules of saving will render again the changes in the back end

the problem: when I re-render I need to show the finished or changed row to the top position so user can see what was changed

Any tips to handle the changed to stay in the top position of the table when re-render?
Thanks a lot

( I don't have code, for now, I just need some logic tips to handle with this )

Comment: Do you sort the items some how?
You can add a flag the time of change to the item like new Date().getTime() and sort all items based on that.

Comment: good @nirshabi I will try that, make sense, so every time I change will show the last change to finished by time, thanks a lot!